# How to specify the installation path in windows_package Ruby script

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there a way to specify the installation path in windows_package resource in chef Ruby script?

I am an newbie in chef script. I've been looking here https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_package.html but can't find the answer.

Appreciate any help on this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are asking how to set the path that a program will be installed into, and this will vary depenIding on the options that can be provided to the msi via command line as well as what route you need to take.  Not sure if you've ever needed to install sql server through using the UI, but an example cookbook that gets this accomplished is here https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sql_server.  You might want to poke around to get an idea of what they are doing.  If you provide the name/path of the specific program you are trying to install, I may be able to provide a more specific answer.  There are many ways to skin a cat here.

Regards,